# Leopard/Snow Leopard, have to implement daytime server by using daemon?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard, launchd

I find there is no daytime server available in leopard/snow leopard. And after reading some documents, the approach I can think of is writing a daemon and put it under /System/Library/LaunchDaemons, so that launchd can run it. I wonder if there is a way to just enable the service rather than writing a new one myself?
  Thanks in advance!

Tianzhou

Answer (score 0):

Please see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16382770/1401034).

It does mean you have to write one yourself but will hopefully streamline the process.