# how to open daytime service on mac using launchctl?

Tags: macos, xinetd

well, there is solution on internet to linux's daytime service startup.
But I can not find solution to Mac.
I don't know if I should find the executable of daytime first, and then write a .plist file, or just there is something built-in, all I need to do is just like on linux -- that is 'turn disable to NO'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't have enough rep to comment so please excuse the answer;

Taken from [here](http://schorsch.efi.fh-nuernberg.de/wiki/index.php/Tutorials/RFC867HowTo)

> 1. Use the Boost.ASIO library for C++ [server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime2.html) and [client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1.html)
> 2. Compile the server as 'boost_daytime_server' and linked into /usr/local/bin/
> 3. Drop the following plist file into /Library/LaunchDaemons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
            <key>Debug</key>
            <false/>
            <key>GroupName</key>
            <string>staff</string>
            <key>Label</key>
            <string>my_organisation.daytime</string>
            <key>OnDemand</key>
            <false/>
            <key>Program</key>
            <string>/usr/local/bin/boost_daytime_server</string>
            <key>ServiceDescription</key>
            <string>Daytime Server with Boost</string>
            <key>UserName</key>
            <string>root</string>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

> 1. And load into OS X

```
sudo lauchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/my_organization.daytime.plist
```

We can test the client using:

```
./client schorsch.efi.fh-nuernberg.de
```

Comment: thank kisamoto. my concern is that, previously in linux world, daytime service is standard, if you need it, just run 'inetd start daytime'. but later, out of secure reason, daytime service is disabled, but if you need it you can still enable it by running xinetd. However, in Mac's world, inetd and xinets all turned into launchctl, and I can not find a simple built-in supported way to start daytime servrice. I can write a simple C++ file to run as daytime server, but I just like to know 'where are all the standard services in Mac that once available in linux distributions?'

Comment: agreed @wuhaochi. I'm sorry this is the only alternative I could come up with for my Mac.
I know that you can compile and run xinetd alongside launchctl (as long as it doesn't try and use the same ports) if it's any consolation.